# What difference between HP and Intel network adapter, both using an Intel controller?

Tags: networking, hardware, nic

For example, the network adapter [HP NC360T](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/networking/nc360t/) PCI card uses the [Intel 82571EB controller](http://www.intel.com/design/network/products/lan/controllers/82571eb.htm).

So, what exactly is the difference between an Intel "fully" branded card, and a HP branded card having an Intel controller?

I've seen pictures of both cards having this controller, and the PCB is very similar, but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HP provides support and warranty services for their own branded hardware. The same for Intel.

That's it.

So if you have an HP server, you use HP components to keep your warranty and support contracts valid. If you stick third party hardware in it, even if it works, you can't get support for it from HP.

Comment: Yet the PCB are a slightly different...

Comment: That's not much of an issue in practice.